# Row of two components. If the text overflows it should start from left in HTML

Tags: html, css, text, alignment, row

[image]

As you can see in the highlighted part in the image there are two components.

1. "Live" blue label
2. The title

The problem is if we use a row, then the overflowed text will continue from the starting point of the second component.
What I want is: I want the overflowed text to start from the starting point of the whole row like the "South Africa" under "Live" label.

Any solution/ recommendation would be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with `display: flex;` (also:`flex-direction: column;`)and setting a maximum width to avoid text continuing behind the live label:

```css
#everthing{
  height: 700px;
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

#title{
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
}
```

```html
<div id="everything">
  <img src="" alt="Main picture">
  <div id="title">
    <img src="" alt="Live">
    <span>Your Title</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now you just have to insert the missing data and the height or width you prefer. For me, it worked out well like this. I used a Image for the Live-Label but it should be possible to use a div.